# Update - No release file, weak signature key

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, repository

I get this error after running `apt-get update` on ubuntu server 16.04:

```
W: The repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.0 Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: http://packages.elastic.co/elasticsearch/1.7/debian/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 46095ACC8568582C1A2699B9D27D666CD88E42B4 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
E: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/xenial/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have seen duplicates of this but they are about a PPA, removing the package via `apt-get remove` does not fix the problem.

There's also that weak signature key for elasticsearch, anything I can do about it?

I installed mongodb and elasticsearch for graylog, encountered some problems and decided to uninstall them and start from scratch.

Thanks for your help!

UPDATES:
mongodb-org is NOT installed.
I followed the link and there is no 3.0 version: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/xenial/mongodb-org/

How can i delete the instruction to fetch that package?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I had to manually remove `mongodb-org-3.0.list` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Hopefully the server wont blowup.